# Should we limit the number of edits per day on old questions?

Tags: discussion, editing

Editing a question has the effect of bumping it on top of the front page.
Should we limit the number of edits done on old questions? Bumping forty old questions in the front page has just the effect to hide the newest questions.

I am asking the question because something I observed between today, and yesterday. I am not putting the blame on who is editing questions; I am wondering if we should not schedule those activities, in the same way it has been done in a different SE site.

Comment: To be honest, I mislike the flavour of this question. So what if someone wants to put some time in with mass edits? As @Jeff says, you could ask for the job to be automated, but mostly we wouldn't expect that. If OP has a problem about the direction others are moving the site, raise that specific issue. But please don't expect us to take sides on whether we agree with *someone* (JSBangs?) doing whatever they do, without even knowing what we're voting on. Quite frankly, EL&U is starting to look like a police state these last few weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you referring to JSBangs removing a tag from 40 different questions? That's the only thing I see at the moment, scrolling down.

If you need to remove a lot of tags, **you should post a request here on meta,** since developers have the ability to destroy tags without causing revisions.

So the mistake in this case is deciding to manually remove a tag with too many questions.

Comment: I was not putting the blame on anybody. As a matter of fact, a question asked August 23, 2010 has been edited yesterday, and there are at least 80 edits done in the past 3 days.

Comment: regardless, if you need to mass retag (let's say 15 or more questions), you should do it by invoking a request on meta to have it done by a developer rather than bumping a ton of questions with tag removal edits, etc.

Comment: Is it that valid for changing the title of questions too?

Comment: @kia depends if it can be automated or not.. tag removal is already so

Comment: I was thinking to a case like the following one: some question titles needs to be changed because they contains a word that we don't prefer to appear; we make a list of the titles that need to be changed, how they need to be changed, and somebody changes them without using the user interface exposed by the SE site.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this brings the related question: **should tag edits really bump questions?** They are most often done either when the question is young, because it was badly tagged by its author (and thus in the top of the list anyway), or on old questions as part of retagging efforts (in which case, do we want to bump it?).

Comment: I was not only referring to tags, for which there is a solution to massive retagging.